# Running a script at scheduled times from Google Cloud VM (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-compute-engine

I am using the Google Cloud Platform to run a virtual Ubuntu Machine, and I would like to schedule a .sh script to run at 08:00 every day. I am currently using the free credit on the Google Cloud Platform, and would ideally keep it this way.

How could I schedule the VM to start-up, and the script to run every day?

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of diffrent methods you can use though, I suppose it would depend on the use case.
assuming its a one-off script file use cronjobs

great resource for editing cronjobs https://crontab.guru/#0_8_1-31_*_*
and scheduling bash script tutorial: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/create-schedule-cron-job-shell-script-linux/

- one off or bashscript: try using cronjobs to schedule script executions.
- Ubuntu Program or project you created: Supervised - like a program controller you can use it to manage specific programs.
- IT Automation multi-clusters: Ansible is pretty popular though there are others
  great if you have multiple clusters or instance of your VM connected using ssh.

Answer (score 1):

At first, have a look at this article [Save money by stopping and starting Compute Engine instances on schedule](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/save-money-by-stopping-and-starting-compute-engine-instances-on-schedule) and then go to the documentation [Scheduling compute instances with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) to find how to use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) and [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) to automatically start and stop Compute Engine instances on a regular schedule using [resource labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources).

After that, follow the official documentation [Ubuntu Cron Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) and configure schedule for your sh script.

As a result, you can start your VM instance, run your script and then stop your VM instance to save some money.